# Can i host my ServerSocket or Java file somewhere on the web?

Tags: java, hosting

Heyy guys. I'm writing a chat application in java, works pretty well. But can i somehow host my Server file or the Serversocket on the web? I want to make it so my friends from other pcs can use the client and connect to the server file which is hosted on the web. Is that possible? Can i host the File/socket online?

Comment: You can always tell your friends your IP address. If you are behind NAT see [Is it possible to host a web server from behind a NAT](https://superuser.com/q/121435)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a java application that opens a `ServerSocket`, it opens a port on your local machine and starts listening for incoming connections. What you do with those connections is up to the implementation of the java code that you write.

The "web" is much less foreign than you are making it out to be. Your own computer can be on the web that you're talking about and people can connect to your chat service. Or you can choose to host it on something like an [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) server.

The following approach is assuming you are behind a pretty standard [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) config.

Once you run your java application, you need to make sure other computers can see you, either inside your [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) or outside on the internet. You want to start testing from as close to your computer as possible, then start expanding outward.

First you need to make sure that your computer's firewall is actually allowing connections on the port that your java application is listening on.

[Opening ports in the Windows Firewall](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html)

[Setting up and opening ports in Linux](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Now computers on your LAN will be able to connect to your java program. Now you need to go one layer out, and [port forward your router](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-port-forward-4163829). This is much less standard so I can't help you too much, but Google can.

At this point, anyone on this internet, knowing your [external ip](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=what%20is%20my%20ip) and what port your java application is listening, can connect to your service.

If you chose to host this on an third party hosting service, you'll need to go through similar steps, but there may be slight differences that you can either ask about, or again Google is a great resource.